# Angular Material - Mat-table row tooltip

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular Material Mat-Table and I wanted to display a tool-tip during mousehover on any row.
Based on row id , I need to match and filter data from mGridDataSource.
I am new to Angular. Can someone please help me on this.

HTML file:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: mGridColumns;"
     [ngClass]="{hovered: row.hovered, highlighted: row.highlighted}"
     (click)="onRowClick(mGridDataSource, row)"
     matTooltip = {{myToolTip}} (mouseover)="getToolTip(row); ">
</mat-row>
```

ts file:

```
getToolTip(row) {

this.matTooltip = '';
   }
```

Comment: What is the current behaviour? No tooltip at all, error, tooltip with no data?

Comment: @FelixLemke - If I assign any text to this.matTooltip, tooltip displays the data but as I mentioned, I need specific row's data from data source which matches row id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the rows attributes directly in the tooltip. Imagine you have the property `tooltipText` in your specific row data object `row`, then you can access this property directly in your template. There is no need to execute a function on mouseover to store the current tooltip inside a component variable.

```
<mat-row
  *matRowDef="let row; columns: mGridColumns;"
  (click)="onRowClick(mGridDataSource, row)"
  [matTooltip]="row.tooltipText">
</mat-row>
```